# Three tables A,B and C exist where in I need to add or concatenate values from C based on formula present in B into A

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables A, B and C. I have to insert values into table A which are available in table C based on formula present in table B.

Example:

TableA::

```
Person loc  Address
--------------------
abc    usa  NULL
def    uk   NULL
```

Tableb::

```
loc formula
--------------------
usa a1+a2+a3
uk  a1+a3
```

Tablec::

```
person  a1        a2     a3
----------------------------------------
abc    dadad    sadada  dadada
def    fkjfkans         kjdvbnskdnb
```

```
execute immediate '
 SELECT 
a.person,
'b.'||replace(formula,'+','||b.') as new_Add,
c.loc,c.a1,c.a2,c.a3
from TableA a,
    TableC c,
    TableB b
WHERE 
a.person = c.Person
and a.loc = b.loc;';
```

I know my query is not complete, but I would like to know if this approach works?

Comment: Yes, you must build dynamically your query in order to embeed there the formulas, which is what you are doinh

Comment: in the above query I am stuck at this place, there is an issue with quotes here i tried adding triple single quotes ''' but it doesn't work

Comment: As Kaushik says in his answer this is not a great design.  Having the formulae in a table means you need to use dynamic SQL.  If I were you I would put the formulae in a PL/SQL function with a meaningful name - your code will be way easier to maintain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a truly poor database design and whoever came up with it(if it's not you) should have a word with me. You have already seen how nightmarish it was to deal with quotes in your query. Moreover, Programs written in Dynamic SQL are always hard to debug and difficult to maintain. I would recommend you to change the model if possible. Remember this whenever you use this code.

```
DECLARE
    v_addr   VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (
        SELECT
            a.person,
            a.loc,
            replace(formula,'+','||') AS true_formula
        FROM
            tablea a
            JOIN tableb b ON a.loc = b.loc
            JOIN tablec c ON a.person = c.person
    ) LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT '
                          || rec.true_formula
                          || ' FROM Tablec   WHERE person = :b_person'
        INTO v_addr
            USING rec.person;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE tablea
         SET
            address =:b_addr
         WHERE
         person =:b_person
            AND loc =:b_loc'
            USING v_addr,rec.person,rec.loc;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e6ee3d2742014466cb5d84f6b860e760)

Comment: thanks for the help, iam trying to push for change in design. But as of now this is the way it has been provided to us

Answer (score 0):

If you have a similar model (conditions restricted to a1, a2 and a3), you can use the below query to generate the kind of data you need for table B:

```
select a.loc,
trim(trailing '+' from (
trim(trailing from (
case when c.a1 IS NOT NULL
    THEN 'a1 + '
    end || 
case when c.a2 IS NOT NULL
    THEN 'a2 + '
    end || 
case when c.a3 IS NOT NULL
    THEN 'a3'
    end   ))))
from A a, C c where a.person = c.person;
```

Comment: the case is not limited to 3 cols it can go up to 7 or 8 columns  based on case, so I would like to make it generic than fixed and the query is driven based on the table b than table c